# Divine apple island

Tags: knowledge, geography, connections-puzzle

Arrange the following words into pairs. What cities are being clued here? What city is missing?

> divine, apple, island, oxford, big, love, novel, lower, rival, refuge, saxony, odysseus, guidance, brotherly

Comment: I see pairs that apply to cities: "Brotherly" + "love" = Philadelphia. "Big" + "apple" = Manhattan. "Divine" + "guidance" = Delphi?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The pairs are:

> divine guidance - Providence / Brown 
>  big apple - New York / Colombia 
>  brotherly love - Philadelphia / Pennsylvania 
>  lower saxony - Hanover / Dartmouth 
>  odysseus island - Ithaca / Cornell 
>  oxford rival - Cambridge / Harvard 
>  novel refuge - New Haven / Yale

That leaves:

> Princeton

To give us:

> The Ivy League.

Credit goes to humn for getting the first three pairs.